# Matlab:Gaussian Model with Variable Mean and Standard Deviation

Tags: matlab, gaussian, noise-generator

I would like to add Gaussian noise Model with variable Standard Deviation (Sigma) and Variable Mean (Mu) to my Output Curve which is shown in the figure below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FcU38.jpg

Following function generates the Output curve expressed in the figure above

```
function c_t = output_function_constrainedK2(t, a1, a2, a3,b1,b2,b3,td, tmax,k1,k2,k3)

K_1   = (k1*k2)/(k2+k3);
K_2   = (k1*k3)/(k2+k3);
DV_free= k1/(k2+k3);


c_t = zeros(size(t));

ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax);


c_t(ind)= conv(((t(ind) - td) ./ (tmax - td) * (a1 + a2 + a3)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');


ind = (t >= tmax);


c_t(ind)= conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');



plot(t,c_t);
axis([0 50  0 1400]);
xlabel('Time[mins]');
ylabel('concentration [Mbq]');
title('Model :Constrained K2');
end
```

The output values for the above function are

```
 output_function_constrainedK2(0:0.1:50,2501,18500,65000,0.5,0.7,0.3,...
 0.28,0.9,0.014,0.051,0.07)
```

Now i would like to add the Gaussian probability distribution function with variable Standard deviation Sigma and mean to the above function, could any one please help me through this , I am an absolute beginner to matlab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

between these lines

```
c_t(ind)= conv((a1 * exp(-b1 * (t(ind) - tmax))+ a2 * exp(-b2 * (t(ind) - tmax))) + a3 * exp(-b3 * (t(ind) - tmax)),(K_1*exp(-(k2+k3)*t(ind)+K_2)),'same');

plot(t,c_t);
```

add the following

```
c_t = c_t + normrnd(mu,sigma,length(c_t),1)
```

refer to the [normrnd](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/normrnd.html) documentation for more information about the normrnd function. Or type

```
help normrnd
```

in the matlab console.

edit to correct this answer according to your last comment:

leave c_t as before, and you will have to create a new vector:

```
c_t_noise = c_t + normrnd(mu,sigma,1,length(c_t))
```

also changed the order of parameteres in normrnd to fit your dimension. to plot the two curves, just use the extended plot, like this:

```
plot(t,c_t, t,c_t_noise)
```

or do a hold on like this

```
plot(t,c_t)
hold on %tells matlab to put plots in the same figure
plot(t,c_t_noise)
hold off %this line if you pretend to make some other plot, desactivate hold on
```

more info about "hold" function in matlab console

```
help hold
```

Comment: The Dimensions of the Vector c_t are <1*501double> ,I am obtaining an error here, I have another Query Once i add Gaussian Noise , how can i possibly compute the error between the Ideal curve which is obtained from plotting c_t   and the curve which would be obtained from adding noise, could you kindly please suggest me

Comment: could you please let me know in which cases i have to use normrnd and normpdf,actually i need to create a probability density function of gaussian noise model, in this case it seems i have to use normpdf

Comment: normrnd will return gaussian noise, while normpdf will return the "bell curve"

Comment: I am incurring an error, my Vector size for c_t is  <1*501double>, kindly suggest me how i can add an array of mean and sigma values to this vector size, Do i have to consider a Vector of 500 Values for Mean  and Sigma,Currently the vector for Mean Varies from [0:45] and Sigma [0:10] ..I am obtaining an error every time with this array..

Comment: i think you will have a noise matrix whit a size of 46*11 (length(Mean)*length(Sigma)). Each Mean(i) and Sigma(j) value will represent a "different noise", so you will need to plot 46*11 different c_t vectors with noise. Just pick an element of the matrix, Mean(i) Sigma(j)

Comment: :So , do i have to write a for loop in this case

Comment: If you see the code that i have written, I would like to add the noise data for 2 intervals first time interval where ind = (t > td) & (t < tmax); and add noise for c_t with mean varying [0:5] and variance [0:3] and for other time  interval  : ind = (t >= tmax); the mean must vary between[6:45] and [4:10]..Could you please let me know if i have to write 2 for loops in this case or is there any best coding alternative